# How to protect lens from fungus

Tags: lens, equipment-protection

How can I have total protection of a lens from fungus?

Comment: total protection? first use powerful UV light to kill anything that may be already in the lens, than seal it in an air tight container (that you also sterilized using UV light) and never take it out of the bag (especially don't attach it to the camera and use it).

Comment: I would be *most* surprised if there were a significant difference between fungus formation in DSLR and MILC lenses; the "only" difference between the two is the registration distance, which isn't going to affect fungus. (Yes, I know there are other differences in things like being optimized for CDAF and PDAF, but that's not going to make any difference either).

Answer (score 2):

Keep it bone dry. If you ensure your lens stays in a zero percent humidity environment then you won't get any mold.